# Receiving image through serial port in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I created an image processing GUI in Qt with openCV, where I opened an image from specific path and processed it. Now I am planning to implement like getting an image from serial port and send that image for further processing. I don't have any idea in doing this,. Any help will be appreciated!

```
void finalv1::openimage()
{

    QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Loa d Image"),".",tr("Image    Files(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));

    imageop = cvLoadImage(filename.toAscii().data());

    cvNamedWindow("image",1);

    cvShowImage("image",imageop); 
}

void finalv1::on_pushButton_open_clicked()
{
   openimage();
}
```

I provided my code for opening an image and the image is an 'IplImage*'.

Comment: the only difference u want is that u want to get image data serially from a source instead of from the file, isn't it?

Comment: You can use http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/ to communicate via the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any features of Qt that allow for serial communication, but if you're using C++, try Boost.Asio.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html